# Racket: How do I get information from a structure that is inside a structure?

Tags: structure, racket

straight to my question :). Lets say we have:

```
    (define-struct person (age sex code))
    (define-struct subject (person times))

    (define P1 (make-subject (make-person 19 'f 'OM29Q) (list 299 194 242 303 243)))
```

Is it possible to get the information from the structure person for example the age? If so how do I implement something like that?

I need that bit of Information to work with that.

I am already familiar with the selector function like (subject-person P1) but that does not help me with my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `a-subject` is a subject structure, then `(subject-person a-subject)` will return a person. To get the age of that person, use the selector `person-age`, that is write: `(person-age (subject-person a-subject))`.